# What is the output of XGboost using 'rank:pairwise'?

Tags: xgboost

I use the python implementation of XGBoost. One of the objectives is `rank:pairwise` and it minimizes the pairwise loss ([Documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md)). However, it does not say anything about the scope of the output. I see numbers between -10 and 10, but can it be in principle -inf to inf?

Comment: did u found what is the output?

Comment: Nope. I did not find the answer yet.

Comment: It also does not say what type of loss it uses. Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 8):

good question. you may have a look in [kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-hotel-recommendations/forums/t/20225/xgboost-for-ranking):

> Actually, in Learning to Rank field, we are trying to predict the relative score for each document to a specific query. That is, this is not a regression problem or classification problem. Hence, if a document, attached to a query, gets a negative predict score, it means and only means that it's relatively less relative to the query, when comparing to other document(s), with positive scores.

Comment: in this case, would it not just be a kind of structured regression problem? Or at least it is more "close" to a regression problem: since we have ground truth ranks, our objective is to assign the ranks such that in aggregate, our new ranking is close to the original ranking. I would imagine we would penalize ranking the #3 item as #200 much more than ranking it as #5

Comment: This does not answer the OP question

Answer (score 7):

It gives predicted score for ranking.
However, the scores are valid for ranking only in their own groups.
So we must set the groups for input data.

For esay ranking, refer to my project [xgboostExtension](https://github.com/bigdong89/xgboostExtension)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your questions correctly, you mean the output of the `predict` function on a model fitted using `rank:pairwise`.

`Predict` gives the predicted variable (`y_hat`).

This is the same for `reg:linear` / `binary:logistic` etc.  The only difference is that `reg:linear` builds trees to `Min(RMSE(y, y_hat))`, while `rank:pairwise` build trees to `Max(Map(Rank(y), Rank(y_hat)))`.  However, output is always `y_hat`.

Depending on the values of your dependent variables, output can be anything.  But I typically expect output to be much smaller in variance vs the dependent variable.  This is usually the case as it is not necessary to fit extreme data values, the tree just needs to produce predictors that are large/small enough to be ranked first/last in the group.

Comment: The question is more aiming at the range of the output. Can it be -9999999999999999 to +9999999999999999999 or is it limited to certain boundaries? E.g. -1000 to 1000.

Comment: As mentioned I expect the range of the output to be smaller than the range of the dependent variable.  But this being said, thats more from a statistical point of view.  Within the code itself,  i don't believe there is any hard constrain on the output.